# syncfusion.compression.base cannot be downloaded because it is not compatible with any project in the solution

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

[image: Hi, I was working on a solution using Visual Studio. While restoring the Nuget, i got the error "syncfusion.compression.base" is missing. When I tried downloading the Nuget, it gave the message given]

Hi, I was working on a solution using Visual Studio. While restoring the Nuget, i got the error "syncfusion.compression.base" is missing. When I tried downloading the Nuget, it gave the message as shown in screenshot. What shall I do now?

Comment: what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> When I tried downloading the Nuget, it gave the message as shown in screenshot. What shall I do now?

You need to figure out which project installed the package before in your solution. You can check it with the package.config file.

After download the package `syncfusion.compression.base` from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Compression.Base/), we could to know this package only have one assembly for .NET framework 46:

[image]

After you figure out which project installed this package, you should check the **project type** and **target framework**, make sure the target framework is .NET 46 and above.

Besides, if can not find this package in the package.config or project.json, you may need to check if your project file contains `HintPath` for this package, like:

```
<Reference Include="Syncfusion.Compression.Base, Version=15.2460.0.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3d67ed1f87d44c89, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Syncfusion.Compression.Base.15.2460.40\lib\net46\Syncfusion.Compression.Base.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

To determine whether the package is what you need, if not, you need delete it in the project file and delete the package in the packages folder.